# Kafka connect mirror maker latency issue from cluster to cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am having 2 Kafka clusters with 2 nodes each with 2 zookeepers for each cluster. They are located in the EU and the US physically. I have successfully configured the mirror maker with the below configurations.

```
Kafka Version : kafka_2.12-3.4.0
Java Version  : Open JDK 1.8.0_372
OS Version    : Linux 5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.aarch64
```

```
mm2.properties
--------------
clusters = A, B
A.bootstrap.servers = xa:9092,xb:9092
B.bootstrap.servers = ya:9092,yb:9092
A->B.enabled = true
A->B.topics = .*
A->B.sync.group.offsets.enabled = true
replication.factor=1
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.replication.factor=1
refresh.topics.enabled=true
refresh.topics.interval.seconds = 1
replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy
```

I can publish data from the EU and successfully consume from the US cluster.  I can publish data from 1 node of the given cluster and consume another node from the same cluster with less than 50ms latency.

Now the issue is the latency between the two clusters. It takes more than 20 seconds with the below configurations.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should never ever have an even number of Zookeeper servers

Comment: Well... How long does it take to consume on US cluster if you write a producer in EU with bootstrap servers for US cluster? In other words, how is your problem unique to MirrorMaker? Network latency across the world is a real thing, and it won't be under a second to consume

Answer (score 0):

It was around 20 secs mirroring delay from EU to US with zookeper based setup. I have re-setup it with KRaft based approach. Now it performs well. Latency reduced 20 secs to 80 ms. No changes in connect mirror makers. Now i have to do the load test with new appraoch.

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-shift-from-zookeeper-to-kraft